# I'm All You Need

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I'm all you need.
>   I bring such joy!
>   I'm seen much differently
>   by a man than by a boy.
>
> Some go without me,
>   some think they do,
>   but the person who should give me away
>   is you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> Love.

I'm all you need.

> See: the Beatles.

I bring such joy!

> Love does bring joy, doesn't it?

I'm seen much differently

by a man than by a boy.

> Adults and children love things in different ways.

-

Some go without me,

> I guess it's possible to go through life without love..

some think they do,

> Angry folks probably often feel as though they cannot love.

but the person who should give me away

is you!

> Give a little bit .... give a little bit of my love to you.

Answer (score 0):

> a... flower or bouquet?

I'm all you need.

> Many a companion will show up with flowers in hand, and that material prize is often all you need for that first encounter.

I bring such joy!

> he/she usually enjoys gifts, even the classic flower pack.

I'm seen much differently
by a man than by a boy.

> It's a tool to win some affection versus "it's a flower. can I eat it?"

Some go without me,

> You don't always need to bring flowers, and other gifts may do. (chocolate)

some think they do,

> You may not intentionally bring flowers as a gift, but a suit often has either a handkerchief or a rose in the chest pocket.

but the person who should give me away
is you!

> Give away those flowers, sir!

Comment: I like your reasoning - not quite what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> Smile

I'm all you need.

> everyone needs smile

I bring such joy!

> smile on someone's face brings joy in their as well as in other's day and life

I'm seen much differently

> There are different types of smile like smile of happiness,smile to hide pain,smile to taunt someone etc..

by a man than by a boy.

> Every person interpret smile differently.

Some go without me,

> Some people spent days without smiling.

some think they do,

> some think they actually did it show someone.

but the person who should give me away is you!

> but the person who gives answer to this que must need to smile.

Comment: Close! The answer I was looking for was @Ian MacDonalds's, though :)